# Libgdx Box2D fixtures that are both sensors and non sensors?

Tags: libgdx, box2d

Let's say I have Bodies A, B, and C each with one fixture. It is possible to have fixtures A and B interact with each other with one or both being a sensor so no physics interaction occurs, but have both A and B have physics interactions with fixture C? So, A-B = no interaction, A-C = interaction, B-C = interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into collision filtering (masking)

By setting up categories and masks for different objects you can control which ones are allowed to interact with each other.

```
// create categories
final short A = 0x0001;  // 0000000000000001 in binary
final short B = 0x0002; // 0000000000000010 in binary
final short C = 0x0004; // 0000000000000100 in binary

// create masks
final short AM = 0x0006 // 0000000000000110 in binary
final short BM = 0x0006 // 0000000000000110 in binary
final short CM = 0x0001 // 0000000000000001 in binary

// apply masks and categories to fixtures
FixtureDef ADef = new FixtureDef();
ADef.filter.categoryBits = A;
ADef.filter.maskBits = AM;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible using mask bits and category bits. These allow fixtures to only interact with certain other fixtures defined using these bits.

Category bits define the fixtures type, the default being 0.

Mask bits define which categories of fixtures the fixture can interact with.

---

So, for A and B to interact with C but not with each other, we need to apply the following category bits:

```
A.filter.categoryBits = 0x0001; //binary: 01
B.filter.categoryBits = 0x0001; //binary: 01
C.filter.categoryBits = 0x0002; //binary: 10
```

And the following mask bits:

```
A.filter.maskBits = 0x0002; //binary: 10
B.filter.maskBits = 0x0002; //binary: 10
C.filter.maskBits = 0x0001; //binary: 01
```

Since A and B are category `0x0001` and C has mask `0x0001`, C can interact with A and B. A and B do not contain `0x0001` in their mask so cannot interact with each other.

---

A more in-depth explanation and example can be found [here](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-filtering).